# How do you create a responsive HTML 5 video on iPad?

Tags: html, ipad, video

I have created an HTML5 video player which is contained within a responsive layout. The video resizes correctly in desktop browsers but doesn't appear correctly on an iPad. There are large black borders to the right and left of the video and the video appears much smaller than it should.

Here is my video player

```
<video controls autoplay="true" poster="image.jpg">
    <source src="video.mp4">
    <source src="video.webm">
</video>
```

And my CSS:

```
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link this will help you to create html5 responsive player,

```
http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/08/html5/responsive-html5-video
```

I recommend you to embed `flowplayer` `(http://flowplayer.org/)` this is responsive, runs in all major browsers.

Have a fun!